# Azure Pipeline Dynamic Matrix variable conditions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The goal is to make it so azure devops pipeline will git diff a commit and find all the directories changes.  Then it will run terraform plan in those directories and if changes are found ask for approval based on environment (dev) then apply those plans that had changes but ignore the ones with no changes.
So far we have come up with the following but really would like it to conditionally apply the "terraform_apply_job" job only if we have stuff to change. We have tried so many different ideas but can't seem to get the pipeline to be able to work well with dynamic variables specially with matrix.

```
variables:
  - name: tf_root_directory
    value: 'DEV'
  - name: tf_repo
    value: 'repo_name'
  - name: terraform_version
    value: 'latest'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Terraform_Plan_Stage
  variables:
    - group: dev
  jobs:
  - job: git_diff_job
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        fetchDepth: 0
      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: 'Git Diff'
        name: git_diff
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            commitId=$(git rev-parse $(Build.SOURCEVERSION))
            changedDirectories=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r $commitId | grep -E '^(A|M|T)' | cut -f 2- | xargs -I{} dirname "{}" | grep -E "$(tf_root_directory)" | sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')

            # TODO: Remove the tf_basename stuff if we end up not using it
            # Convert CSV to JSON
            jsonOutput="{}"
            IFS=',' read -ra changedDirectoriesArray <<< "$changedDirectories"
            for item in "${changedDirectoriesArray[@]}"; do
              key=changed_$(basename "$item" | tr '-' '_')
              basename=$(basename "$item")
              jsonOutput=$(jq -c --arg key "$key" --arg basename "$basename" --arg value "$item" '. + { ($key): { tf_directory: $value, tf_basename: $basename , artifact_key: $key }  }' <<< "$jsonOutput")
            done

            # Set the variable to make it available to subsequent tasks
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ChangedDirectories;isOutput=true]$jsonOutput"
  - job: terraform_plan_job
    dependsOn: git_diff_job
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(dependencies.git_diff_job.outputs['git_diff.ChangedDirectories'], '{}'))
    strategy:
      matrix: $[ dependencies.git_diff_job.outputs['git_diff.ChangedDirectories'] ]
    steps:
      - template: templates/tf-plan-template.yml
        parameters:
          artifact_key: $(artifact_key)
          tf_directory: $(tf_directory)
          tf_az_accesskey: $(TF_AZ_ACCESSKEY)
          tf_version: $(terraform_version)
          TF_VAR_tenant_id: $(TF_VAR_tenant_id)
          TF_VAR_subscription_id: $(TF_VAR_subscription_id)
          servicePrincipalId: $(servicePrincipalId)
          servicePrincipalKey: $(servicePrincipalKey)
- stage: Terraform_Apply_Stage
  dependsOn: Terraform_Plan_Stage
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(dependencies.Terraform_Plan_Stage.outputs['terraform_plan_job.git_diff.ChangedDirectories'], '{}'))
  variables:
    - group: dev
  jobs:
  - deployment: terraform_approval
    environment: dev
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - download: none
  - job: terraform_apply_job
    condition: succeeded()
    dependsOn: terraform_approval
    strategy:
      matrix: $[ stageDependencies.Terraform_Plan_Stage.git_diff_job.outputs['git_diff.ChangedDirectories'] ]
    steps:
      - template: templates/tf-apply-template.yml
        parameters:
          artifact_key: $(artifact_key)
          tf_directory: $(tf_directory)
          tf_az_accesskey: $(TF_AZ_ACCESSKEY)
          tf_version: $(terraform_version)
          TF_VAR_tenant_id: $(TF_VAR_tenant_id)
          TF_VAR_subscription_id: $(TF_VAR_subscription_id)
```

Here is the plan template

```
# tf-plan-template..yml

parameters:
  artifact_key: ""
  tf_directory: ""
  tf_az_accesskey: ""
  tf_version: ""
  TF_VAR_tenant_id: ""
  TF_VAR_subscription_id: ""

steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: TerraformInstaller@1
    inputs:
      terraformVersion: ${{ parameters.tf_version }}
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Fetch credentials for azure
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'Azure_dev_it'
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID;]$tenantId"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID;]$servicePrincipalId"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET;]$servicePrincipalKey"
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      useGlobalConfig: true
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
    name: tf_plan
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Run Terraform commands for each changed directory
        terraform init -backend-config="access_key=${{ parameters.tf_az_accesskey }}" -backend-config="key=$(basename $PWD).tfstate"
        terraform validate
        terraform plan -input=false -out tf.plan -detailed-exitcode
        if [ $? -eq 2 ]; then
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedDetected;isOutput=true]true"
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.tf_directory }}
      failOnStderr: true
    env:
      TF_VAR_subscription_id: ${{ parameters.TF_VAR_subscription_id }}
      TF_VAR_tenant_id: ${{ parameters.TF_VAR_tenant_id }}
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['tf_plan.changedDetected'], 'true'))
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.tf_directory }}/tf.plan'
      ArtifactName: '${{ parameters.artifact_key }}-$(Build.BuildId)-tfplan'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

We have tried all kind of stuff and are looking for suggestions on this.